# Why does Travis CI fails to build Python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a simple Python script that uses Microsoft's API ( Pywin32 ). I am able to run the project successfully in my local machine but in Travis , it throws an error -

```
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 17.9MB/s 
Collecting pylint==2.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/06/ecef826f319055e6b231716730d7f9047dd7524ffda224b521d989f085b6/pylint-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (750kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 757kB 18.9MB/s 
Collecting pywin32==224 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==224 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32==224 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
The command "pip install -r requirements.txt" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

In my local system Python version is `3.6.6` and pip is `18.1` . But if you notice in Travis , pip version is `10.0.1` . Could this be the issue ?

My travis.yml file contains -

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.6.6"
pip:
  - "18.1"
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
script:
  - python main.py
```

The Python package pywin32==224 exists and can be downloaded on my local machine so I guess the error is not from their side.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT -**

After trying to install Python , the following error resulted :

```
0.01s$ source ~/virtualenv/python3.6/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 3.6.3
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
0.08s$ choco install python3
choco: command not found
The command "choco install python3" failed and exited with 127 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

**EDIT 2 -**

The new .travis.yml :

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
os: windows
before_install:
        - choco install python3
        - export PATH="/c/Python37:/c/Python37/Scripts:$PATH"
        - python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
script:
  - python main.py
```

The output -

```
Worker information

The language 'python' is currently unsupported on the Windows Build Environment.
Let us know if you'd like to see it: https://travis-ci.community/c/environments/windows. Thanks for understanding!
```

Comment: I believe, by default Travis running Linux, so there is no win api there. Have you tried adding `os: windows` in .travis.yml? See https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-10-11-windows-early-release

Comment: Yes tried , but unfortunately os : windows doesn't support Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pywin32` is WinAPI wrapper, so it's Windows-only package, you cannot use it on Linux.

Travis CI runs on Linux by default, but since October 2018 there is possibility to use Windows by adding `os: windows` in your `.travis.yml` file. Check out [Travis blog post](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-10-11-windows-early-release) on this.

However since it's "early access" feature it still misses a lot of stuff including [Python support](https://travis-ci.community/t/python-support-on-windows/241/12). So if you need Python now - the only way is to install it manually, i.e. like [here](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/translation-finder/blob/master/.travis.yml#L20-L26)

Updated example (April 2020) with Python 3.8 which seems to be default now:

```
- os: windows
  language: sh
  python: "3.8"
  before_install:
        - choco install python3
        - export PATH="/c/Python38:/c/Python38/Scripts:$PATH"
        - python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Updated the question .

Comment: Updated output still seems like Linux output. You must have `os: windows` in any case.

Comment: Nope, no changes. Seems like Python is not supported at all. Updated (Edit 2 )

Comment: @BoudhayanDev please read carefully the content of the last link. There are already projects using it successfully. You should not use `language: python` because it's not supported, you have to install everything you need by yourself

Comment: Note that now the path is /c/Python38